# Session cookie timeout limit

Tags: magento-1.9, session, cookie, timeout

Is there a maximum timeout that we can set for the session cookie?
Can I set it up to 1 year for example?

Comment: One year cookie time should like this `setcookie("cookiename",'somevalue',time()+31556926 ,'/');`

Answer (score 2):

[As written on stackoverflow by Joeri Hendrickx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290474/1480397)

> All cookies expire as per the [cookie specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html), so this is
>   not a PHP limitation.
>
> Use a far future date. For example, set a cookie that expires in ten
>   years:
>
> ```
> setcookie(
>   "CookieName",
>   "CookieValue",
>   time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
> );
> ```
>
> Note that if you set a date past **2038** in PHP, the number will wrap
>   around and you'll get a cookie that expires instantly.

Comment: Is it possible to go the Magento Backend and in Session Cookie Management/Cookie Lifetime set that value (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 315360000)? Will it work?

Comment: If you don't have a problem storing it I assume yes.